# How do I find all equivalent elements from a Symmetric Closure using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find all equivalent elements from symmetric closure using the Haskell code in **Listing 1** .

`symm` is a list of tuples representing a set of equivalences on the set *{a,b,c,d,l,m}*. The equivalences are symmetric, if we have *(x,y)* then we have *(y,x)*.

```
[('d','c'),('c','d'),('c','b'),('c','a'),('l','m'),('b','c'),('a','c'),('m','l')]
```

This relation partitions into two equivalence classes (*a=b=c=d*) and (*l=m*). 
I wish to create a list of elements that are equivalent to a given element. For example, `allEqual 'a' symm` should give `"bcd"` and `allEqual 'l' symm` should give `"m"`.

**Listing 1**  works for  `allEqual x symm` when x='l' and x='m', but not for the other cases.

My current incorrect thinking behind the code is as follows:

If `x` is equal to the first or second element in the current tuple then find a tuple containing the next element from `symm` with the current tuple and its inverse removed

else

continue searching `symm` with the first tuple removed.

I think that the continued search with the removed leading tuple (the else above) is not a good idea as that tuple may be required later in the search. However, I cannot think of another way of moving through the list of tuples.

**Listing 1**

```
import Data.List as L

symm = [('d','c'),('c','d'),('c','b'),('c','a'),('l','m'),('b','c'),('a','c'),('m','l')]

deleteSymPairs (x,y) xs =  L.delete (x,y) (L.delete (y,x) xs)

allEqual  :: Eq t =>  t -> [(t,t)]  ->  [t]
allEqual x  [] = []
allEqual x  (y:xs) | (x == (fst y)) = ((snd y) : (allEqual (snd y)  (deleteSymPairs y xs))) 
                   | (x == (snd y)) = ((fst y) : (allEqual (fst y)  (deleteSymPairs y xs)))
                   | otherwise =  (allEqual x  xs)

test1 = allEqual 'a' symm 
test2 = allEqual 'm' symm 
test3 = allEqual 'l' symm
```

If possible I would like to keep to vanilla Haskell using lists, though maybe sets are needed?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Your closure does not look like a transitive closure: we have `('a','c')` and `('c','b')` but no `('a','b')` ?

Comment: @chi Yes. I will edit the question

Comment: If the closure is symmetric but not transitive, then you'll never need to use a tuple you already eliminated

Comment: In your recursive call, you change the value you're searching for; if a thing is equivalent to multiple other things, this means only the first match in the list is considered. One fix would be to recurse *twice* (once continuing with the current value and once with the newly discovered equivalent value) and combine the results somehow.

Comment: Side note: you may like to Google the phrase "union find".

Comment: So I coded up a solution myself as a precursor to writing an answer. It leads me to this question: why do you demand that `allEqual 'a' symm` be `"bcd"` instead of `"abcd"`? After all, `'a'` is related to `'c'` and `'c'` is related to `'a'`, so the transitive closure of `symm` should relate `'a'` to itself.

Comment: @Dan The reason I want "bcd" is that I am trying to replicate code from a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2352686_Qualitative_Temporal_Reasoning_in_GIS_-_Ordered_Time_Scales), which requires all elements deemed equivalent (equal?) to a given element.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne At a quick glance, nothing in that paper seems to suggest to me that `"bcd"` would be a better answer than `"abcd"` to this query. If you believe it does, can you be specific about where (and why), please?

Comment: @Dan Yes you are correct.. My interpretation of sets and a recursive data structure used in the paper is incorrect. But I could not get the code as written to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive solution (i.e. not using the standard union-find data structure) is to just do depth-first search. As usual with depth-first search, we'll keep track of a "set" of nodes that we know are equivalent and have already thoroughly explored for neighbors together with a "set" of frontier nodes that we have just discovered are equivalent but haven't yet searched for neighbors. We need to keep track of both for the usual cycle-avoidance reasons. We'll know we're done with the search when the frontier is empty.

That's the big picture. Now the nitty-gritty. Let's start with a helper function to compute the unadorned, un-transitively-closed neighbor function of the relation.

```
related :: Eq t => t -> [(t, t)] -> [t]
related t rel = [t'' | (t', t'') <- rel, t == t']
```

Now we can do our DFS. Initially we don't know of any equivalent nodes, and our frontier is the immediate neighbors of our input value.

```
transitivelyRelated :: Eq t => t -> [(t,t)] -> [t]
transitivelyRelated t rel = go (related t rel) [] where
    go [] ts = ts
    go frontier ts = go frontier' ts' where
        ts' = frontier ++ ts
        frontier' = [ t'
                    | t <- frontier
                    , t' <- related t rel
                    , t' `notElem` ts'
                    ]
```

If we wanted the reflexive transitive closure instead, we could start with the simpler `go [t] []` instead of `go (related t rel) []`.

However, this is quite inefficient -- something like O(n^3), I think -- compared to the standard way of computing the reflexive symmetric transitive closure which is basically as close to O(n) as it is possible to get without actually being O(n), so I strongly recommend that you step away from only using lists.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  With input  `"c"` the output contains duplicates. I add   `(L.nub frontier) ++  ts` which seems to fix this,

Answer (score 0):

If the closure is **symmetric but not transitive**, you'll never need to look at a tuple you already eliminated.

Also, I'd split the question in two cases: all permutations are present vs not all are.

#### All permutations are present:

What I mean is, if `('a','b')` is present, then so is `('b','a')`. This is the case in your example.

In this case, you can simplify your algorithm by only looking at one element of the pair:

```
import qualified Data.List as L

allEqual :: Eq t =>  t -> [(t,t)]  ->  [t]
allEqual x = L.nub . allEqual' x
  where
    allEqual' x  [] = []
    allEqual' x  (y:ys)
      | x == fst y = snd y : allEqual' x ys
      | otherwise  =         allEqual' x ys
```

Note that using `nub` is more efficient (`O(nlogn)`) than filtering every element in the list (`O(n2)`)

Furthermore, you can make this function a bit more readable (in my opinion) by using filter and map

```
allEqual :: Eq t =>  t -> [(t,t)]  ->  [t]
allEqual x ys = L.nub . map snd . filter ((==x) . fst) $ ys
```

#### Not all permutations are present

This is similar to your version, only difference is again I'd use `nub` instead of your `deleteSymPairs`:

```
allEqual  :: Eq t =>  t -> [(t,t)]  ->  [t]
allEqual x = L.nub . allEqual' x
  where
    allEqual' x  [] = []
    allEqual' x  (y:ys)
      | x == fst y = snd y : allEqual' x ys
      | x == snd y = fst y : allEqual' x ys
      | otherwise =  allEqual' x  ys
```

Comment: In the question, it is specified that `allEqual 'a' symms` should be `"bcd"`. All of your solutions produce just `"c"`.

Comment: @Daniel Didn't read that, but to get "bcd" you need a transitive group, op said only symmetric

Comment: Demanding that you be given a transitive relation is one possible solution. Computing the transitive closure inside `allEqual` is another (analogous to the way your final proposal computes the symmetric closure inside `allEqual`). To me, computing the transitive closure seems to be the goal/intent of the question.

Comment: @Lorenzo The inputs are an element and a symmetric closure. The output should be a list of elements that are equivalent to the input element.

Comment: @patrick again, if it's a symmetric closure, 'a' only relates to 'c'

Comment: But I'll post the function for a transitive one as well